# Prove that $x^4 + 1 ≥ 4x$ for all real numbers x.

Tags: inequality

> > Prove that $x^4 + 1 ≥ 4x$ for all real numbers x.

What I have attempted:

Consider 
$$x^4+1≥ 4x$$

$$\Leftrightarrow x^4+1+2x^2 \geq 4x+2x^2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (x^2+1)^2 \geq 2(x^2+2x+1) - 2 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (x^2+1)^2 - 2(x+1)^2 +2 \geq 0 $$

Now this is where I am stuck, am I on the correct track?

Comment: This isn't true. At $x=1$ you have $2 \geq 4$.

Comment: This would be a better problem is it were $x^4+3$.  First, it would be true and second, equality is achieved at $x=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(x)=x^4+1$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}$. Let we consider the equation of the tangent line at $x=1$: it is $g(x)=4(x-1)+2$. $f(x)\geq g(x)$ implies:

$$ x^4+1 \geq 4x-2. $$
As already remarked, the original inequality actually does not hold: just consider what happens at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x = 1$

$$2 \geq 4$$

Your statement is not valid for all the reals.

Comment: Ah sorry should change my tag..

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

The inequality is true for all
$$\displaystyle x\in \mathbb{R} \,\backslash\, \left(\frac{a-b}{2}, \frac{a+b}{2}\right)$$
($\frac{a-b}{2}\approx 0.251,\frac{a+b}{2}\approx 1.49$)

where
$$a=\sqrt{c+d}$$
$$b=\sqrt{\frac{8}{\sqrt{c+d}}-(c+d)}$$
again where
$$c=\frac 13\sqrt[3]{216-24\sqrt{78}}$$
$$d=\frac{2\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{78}}}{\sqrt[3]{9}}$$